# Attempting to Union two tables in SQL(same column, data type and where clause)

Tags: sql, t-sql

HI I been trying to combine out come of these two queries using simple union or use CAT and then union but its not working:

my queries as below:
{

```
    ;WITH tb1 as

(
                        select 
                                 Venue
                                ,convert(date,event, 103) as EventDate
                                ,RoomName
                                ,SPECIALTY
                                CONSULTANT_NAME
from test.dbo.test_tbl1
WHERE convert(date,event, 103) >= '2019-01-01' and convert(date,event, 103) <= '2019-12-01')
select * from tb1
where
                                 SPECIALTY like 'Business%'
                                or (CONSULTANT_NAME like '%john, Jx%') 
                                or (CONSULTANT_NAME like '%Sam, Sx%')



;WITH tb2 as

(
                        select 
                                 Venue
                                ,convert(date,event, 103) as EventDate
                                ,RoomName
                                ,SPECIALTY
                                CONSULTANT_NAME
from test.dbo.test_tbl2
WHERE convert(date,event, 103) >= '2019-01-01' and convert(date,event, 103) <= '2019-12-01')
select * from tb2
where
                                 SPECIALTY like 'Business%'
                                or (CONSULTANT_NAME like '%john, Jx%') 
                                or (CONSULTANT_NAME like '%Sam, Sx%')
}

at the end of first query if I try to put tab2 as: 

,tb2 as

( select ....)
```

its showing error

Any help to indicate right direction is appreciated.

Comment: `Post the error !!`

Comment: its says syntax error near ',' which is referring to ,tb2 (when i try to put the second table under 1st one as CAT)

Comment: you forgot two commas right before CONSULTANT_NAME

Comment: no issue with comma, no indication of error there

Comment: of course it's an issue! just put it where it belongs and see the magic happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use something like this:

```
SELECT 
     Venue
    ,CONVERT(date,event, 103) AS EventDate
    ,RoomName
    ,SPECIALTY
    ,CONSULTANT_NAME
FROM test.dbo.test_tbl1
WHERE CONVERT(date,event, 103) >= '2019-01-01' AND CONVERT(date,event, 103) <= '2019-12-01') AND (SPECIALTY LIKE 'Business%' OR CONSULTANT_NAME LIKE '%john, Jx%' OR CONSULTANT_NAME LIKE '%Sam, Sx%')

UNION 

SELECT 
     Venue
    ,CONVERT(date,event, 103) AS EventDate
    ,RoomName
    ,SPECIALTY
    ,CONSULTANT_NAME
FROM test.dbo.test_tbl2
WHERE CONVERT(date,event, 103) >= '2019-01-01' AND CONVERT(date,event, 103) <= '2019-12-01') AND (SPECIALTY LIKE 'Business%' OR CONSULTANT_NAME LIKE '%john, Jx%' OR CONSULTANT_NAME LIKE '%Sam, Sx%')
```